# Using Flask and WTForms, how should one reference a server variable to modify upon form submit with POST?

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

If one wanted to operate the on the "next_object" what would need to be done to the code below to allow for the objects or an id of the object to be passed back to "send_and_receive():" with a post method?

For the sake of the people who want to immediately close this as a duplicate of referencing in an insecure way, I am asking for doing this with POST not GET.

routes.py code

```
@app.route('/statistics', methods=['POST'])
def send_and_receive():
    reference_form = ReferenceForm()
    if reference_form.object_approved.data:
        library.approve_object(??reference_object_id_or_object??)
        return redirect('index')
    if reference_form.object_rejected.data:
        library.reject_object(??reference_object_id_or_object??)
        return redirect('index')
    next_object = library.get_next()
    return render_template('site.html', reference_form=reference_form, next_object=next_object)
```

site.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<form  action="" method="post">
  <p>{{next_object.string()}}</p>
  <p>{{ reference_form.object_approved() }}</p>
  <p>{{ reference_form.object_rejected() }}</p>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Forms.py code

```
class ReferenceForm(FlaskForm):
    object_approved = SubmitField("Approve")
    object_rejected = SubmitField("Reject")
```

Comment: Add the id as a [HiddenField](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/fields.html#wtforms.fields.HiddenField) to the `ReferenceForm` class.

Comment: No data survives in the hidden field upon return just like every other field.

Comment: Did you set the app's `SECRET_KEY` and include the `csrf_token` hidden field ? See simple example answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you set the app's SECRET_KEY and render out the hidden fields in the html template, including the automatically added ([see documentation](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html#csrf-protection)) `csrf_token` hidden field.

A simple example:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SubmitField, HiddenField


class ReferenceForm(FlaskForm):
    object_id = HiddenField()
    object_approved = SubmitField("Approve")
    object_rejected = SubmitField("Reject")


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '123456790'


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    _form = ReferenceForm()
    _form.object_id.data = 42

    if _form.validate_on_submit():

        flash('Object ID:{}'.format(_form.object_id.data))
        print(_form.object_approved.data)
        print(_form.object_rejected.data)
        print(_form.object_id.data)
        # process form blah blah
        # would be usual to return a redirect here     

    return render_template('index.html', reference_form=_form)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
  {% if messages %}
    <ul class=flashes>
    {% for message in messages %}
      <li>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}

<form action="" method="post">
    {{ reference_form.object_id() }}
    {{ reference_form.csrf_token() }}

    <p>{{ reference_form.object_approved() }}</p>
    <p>{{ reference_form.object_rejected() }}</p>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Note how the html gets rendered, especially the two hidden fields, `object_id` and `csrf_token`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

  


<form action="" method="post">
    <input id="object_id" name="object_id" type="hidden" value="42">
    <input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="IjBjNGIwNWE2NDA5NDVmZjhiMjU3Y2E5YTIwY2QwMGVlMTMxYzViYzUi.X0oupA.g9KjI79vZvfEIW1mwzR7nvHc6Yc">

    <p><input id="object_approved" name="object_approved" type="submit" value="Approve"></p>
    <p><input id="object_rejected" name="object_rejected" type="submit" value="Reject"></p>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't realize that I would have to serve the hidden field and I guess I just validate it when it gets back like an input.